# Every time person will go to a page, int will increase in the database

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I want vote_count to increase everytime a member views the page.

from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3, etc.

I have done this but it doesn't really work:

```
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'vote', '') or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('counter') or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `vote_count` (`vote_number`) VALUES (NULL)");
    mysql_close();
```

it stays empty.

My row looks like this:
[image: img]

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop using `mysql_` functions; they are deprecated
2. Use error handling to catch errors:

   `mysql_query("INSERT INTO vote_count (vote_number) VALUES (NULL)") or die( mysql_error() );`
3. The column does not allow `NULL`.
4. Use `UPDATE` to **update**/increment the count:

   `UPDATE vote_count SET vote_number = vote_number + 1`
5. Use a password.

Comment: I have a password, just haven't included it here.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the value and just want to update it. Hence, you just need to increment its value in 1.

Hence, you can use

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `vote_count` SET vote_number=vote_number+1");
```

Comment: The query is correct, have you checked a basic `SELECT ... FROM ...` to see if it works with current database conexion?

Comment: mysql_query('SELECT FROM * `vote_count`');
$rcvotes = $row['vote_number'];
if (empty($rcvotes)) {
$rcvotes = 0;
}

$counter = strval(str_pad($rcvotes, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into stopping people from upping the views/votes by refreshing:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['voted']) && $_SESSION['voted']){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `vote_count` SET vote_number=vote_number+1") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
    $_SESSION['voted'] = true;
}
else{
    //Already voted.
}
```

Comment: Out of scope of this question

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk It is until he comes back looking for a way to prevent multiple votes :) I see no issue with providing somebody with a good practice and a nod in the right direction instead of simply giving them a blunt answer and sending them on their way.